# Rails check_box on Heroku not behaving properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I've got some boolean attributes in a Rails 3.1 model and two new ones I just added via a migration aren't working properly on Heroku (Cedar). They are working properly locally, where I'm also using PostgreSQL (ver 9).

Migration:

```
class AddNotificationSettingsToCollections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :collections, :email_comments, :boolean   , :default => true
    add_column :collections, :email_selections, :boolean , :default => true
  end
end
```

View (HAML)

```
%li
  %label{:for => 'collection_email_comments'}
    = f.check_box :email_comments
    Email me when comments are made
%li
  %label{:for => 'collection_email_selections'}
    = f.check_box :email_selections
    Email me when a selection is made
```

Problem is, the checkbox is ALWAYS displaying as unchecked, but the model ALWAYS has the attributes set as true when I check the console. When I tail the Heroku log file, I can see that the correct parameter is being set for these fields (1).

Am I missing something? I have other boolean fields in this form that work fine. Could this be related to the default value?

Comment: The checkboxes are unchecked when you have a new Collection instance (i.e. freshly created and not yet in the database) or a Collection that has been loaded from the database?

Comment: Mine just fixed itself after several hours.  :/

Comment: Definitely has nothing to do with the default value in the schema. You  might want to post your controller action code.

Comment: I had somewhat of a similar issue. In my case the value wasn't getting saved to the database. It was working locally but no on Heroku. A restart of the dynos fixed the issue. Adding this comment for others that might come across it, or for my future self!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well. I ended up with a stupid workaround. I know it's not a good solution, but this is mine:

```
= f.check_box :email_comments, {:checked => (@collection.new_record? ? true : @collection.active)}
```

It's ugly, but it did the job for me on Heroku in an identical setup. Hopefully there is a more elegant solution out there...